# Can we 're'+verb any verb?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs, prefixes, participial-adjectives

It's a strange question but can we add 're' to any verb?

- replan
- revisit
- rechange
- reinsist

Is it possible to add 're' to compound verbs?

- refind out
- rebring back
- refly over
- reshout out

Does it work same way with adjectives?

- regrown
- retransported
- refound
- rewidened

Comment: Is *reensist* a typo for *reenlist*?

Comment: @snailplane misspelled insist, T9 you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is no, though the prefix re- seems to have more inherent forgiveness in its usage than any other prefix in the English language.

Many *stative verbs* by their very nature would become nonsensical if prefixed by 're-'. Stative verbs usually describe states (not actions) that last for some time. (Example: like, appear, believe, hate, belong) A state continues over a period of time and has no immediate beginning and the end is unknown. The prefix 're-' on the other hand implies repetition, so the two obviously don't mesh well. To give examples, **re-be**, **re-want**, **re-have**, **re-need** and so on don't really make sense in day-to-day usage.

(there are of course, exceptions - certain stative verbs can also be dynamic, so **re-possess**, **re-think** and so on are acceptable.)

However with *dynamic verbs*, there seems to be a general acceptance that re- can prefix most verbs, particularly in day-to-day english usage.

The [Wictionary article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/re-) on re- sums it up best:

> re- is highly productive, to the point of being almost grammaticalized
>   — almost any verb can have re- applied, especially in colloquial
>   speech. Notable exceptions to this include all forms of be and the
>   modal verbs can, should, etc. When used productively, it is always
>   pronounced /ɹiː/.

Comment: What to think of such words like retell? Does it mean tell again or say something someone else said?

Comment: retell means that the **story** is being told again. _Who_ is telling the story doesn't seem to be a factor...

Comment: Resell is another such example.